# How to Extract Transit Stop locations from Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building an application that requires the name, long, and lat for the transit stops in my area.

Google Maps API displays this information, but in this scenario I can't use the API and need to extract this information to an XML format.

I'm not sure if this is possible and can't find any reference to this on the web.

Any Ideas how I can extract the transit stop long, lat, and name from Google Maps, preferably to an XML format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now it's possible to get this done, check this post:

[Detect the nearest transit stop from the given location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340800/detect-the-nearest-transit-stop-from-the-given-location)

And if you want to see it in action try this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/aZrvs/